# NSException on import of matplotlib, kivy in OSX

Tags: python, matplotlib, kivy

I'm working on some kivy code that's working fine on windows 10, but crashes on osx sierra, I've isolated that the crash happens when I import kivy.core.window along side matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import kivy.core.window
```

It also crashes without `matplotlib.use("TkAgg")`. This is just included to show that the issue isn`t fixed by this as other questions suggest.

The output from the exception is:

```
2017-03-08 13:33:32.461 Python[28614:209475] -[SDLApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1020ea6c0
2017-03-08 13:33:32.464 Python[28614:209475] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SDLApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1020ea6c0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation  0x00007fffa8716e7b  __exceptionPreprocess + 171
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fffbd300cad objc_exception_throw + 48
...
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

What could be causing this, and where do I start looking to debug this type of exception it?

After solving this I ran into a perhaps related problem, noted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42673733/nsexception-in-kivy-with-matplotlib-and-tkinter).

Comment: This looks like perhaps kivy and SDL are unhappy with each other. How did you install all the bits and pieces?

Comment: I honestly can't remember the exact details of the installation process but Matplotlib was installed way back, and updated with pip later. Kivy was installed using homebrew following this: [link](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-osx.html#using-macports-with-pip).

Comment: You could try their dev version or installing matplot into the bundled virtual environment they provide. I don't see how the homebrew instructions can guarantee you're getting a compatible version of SDL

Comment: Could you describe your suggestion in detail? The homebrew/pip installation is the recommended method on the site, why do you suspect it's not working?

Comment: What happens if you import kivy first?

Comment: Well, I guess first you should determine how it's not working. Does the kivy import alone blow up?

Comment: Kivy alone does not cause any problems. Kivy first also causes exception

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solved this problem through running

```
pip install kivy-gardens
garden install matplotlib
```

I'm not sure why this worked, but it did remove this root of the NSException.

I'm now getting a different NSException caused by a different interplay of dependencies that I'll post as a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42673733/nsexception-in-kivy-with-matplotlib-and-tkinter).